# CSS transition not doing animation when changing right and top

Tags: css, sass, position, transition

```
.ez-active
  &.ez-fixed-top-right
    position: fixed
    right: 0
    top: 0
    transition: top 500ms ease-in-out 0s, right 500ms ease-in-out 0s
```

I want it to slide into the top right when it's clicked.. but for some reason it just teleports.

Answer (score 0):

Update: your code seems to be fully functional.  Remember that the transition should be set on the default state of your element, not on the 'active' state.

```js
$(".clickable").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("ez-active");
})
```

```css
.ez-fixed-top-right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    transition: top 500ms ease-in-out 0s, right 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
}

.ez-active .ez-fixed-top-right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clickable">
  <div class="ez-fixed-top-right">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Turns out I'm wrong about the extra seconds.  I'm leaving this here for now in case you are reading it, since the sample is functional.  But we're going to need more of your code to figure out why it isn't working.